# SSAS: calculations in the cube

Tags: scope, expression, ssas, mdx

I need to divide my calculations into three groups:
- which applied to base cells only (leaves)
- which applied to all cells
- which applied to consolidating cells only (cells of upper hierarchy levels)
For example, I have hierarchy: Year-Quarter-Month.
Base cells of this hierarchy in the "Month" and consolidating cells in a "Year" and "Quarter".

For base cells I can write this "scope":

```
SCOPE (
   [Measures].[Value] ,
   [DimProducts].[Name].[Donut] , 
   [DimTime].[Month].CHILDREN       // month only
      );
THIS = [Measures].[Value]*2+100500;
END SCOPE;
```

And I don't know how to write the "scope" for consolidating cells? I can't to create a "scope" for each hierarchy level such as:

```
SCOPE (
   [Measures].[Value] ,
   [DimProducts].[Name].[Donut] , 
   [DimTime].[Quarter].CHILDREN    // quarter only
      );
...
END SCOPE;
SCOPE (
   [Measures].[Value] ,
   [DimProducts].[Name].[Donut] , 
   [DimTime].[Year].CHILDREN       // year only
      );
...
END SCOPE;
```

Because there are many dimensions and hierarchy levels and calculations must be applied to all of them.
Maybe there is a simply way for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MDX functions in `SCOPE`'s subcube expression.

Supposing your *Year-Quarter-Month* user hierarchy has *Year*, *Quarter* and *Month* levels, you can use the following expression to address levels above the *Month* level.

```
SCOPE ( [Measures].[Value]
      , [DimProducts].[Name].[Donut]
      , Descendants( [DimTime].[Year-Quarter-Month].[All]
                   , [DimTime].[Year-Quarter-Month].[Quarter]
                   , SELF_AND_BEFORE
                   )
      );
...
END SCOPE;
```

Reference:

- [`Descendants` MDX function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146075.aspx)
- [`SCOPE` MDX statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145989.aspx)